# fullcalendar dragging events update and insert into database

Tags: jquery, json, fullcalendar

I'm trying to use the fullcalendar with dragging events. What i want is when i drag an event to the calendar that the event added to my database. What i also want is when i drag an existing event from the calendar to another date update in the database

Fetching the existing events with json is no problem.

Maybe someone can help me a little further with an example or some information.

This is what my code look like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    /* initialize the external events
    -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

    $('#external-events div.external-event').each(function() {

        // create an Event Object (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)
        // it doesn't need to have a start or end
        var eventObject = {
            title: $.trim($(this).text()) // use the element's text as the event title
        };

        // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
        $(this).data('eventObject', eventObject);

        // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
        $(this).draggable({
            zIndex: 999,
            revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
            revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
        });

    });


    /* initialize the calendar
    -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: true,
        events: "json-events.php",
        droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
        drop: function(date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped

            // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
            var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

            // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
            var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

            // assign it the date that was reported
            copiedEventObject.start = date;
            copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;

            // render the event on the calendar
            // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

            // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
            if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                $(this).remove();
            }

        }
    });


});
```

Comment: This is just a copy-paste of a part of the plain example from Arshaw. Not very helpful at all.

Answer (score 1):

*Can you clarify on what is happening inside your drop callback?*

Is the event getting displayed correctly in calendar?

Call ajax methods inside your javascript to update your database by calling appropriate server method.